# Select column in a selected row using selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have to select a row in a table where there are multiple rows and in that I have to click on a column link . This column link has the same xpath in all the rows.

example:

```
row1  name1     updatelink
row2  name2     updatelink
row3  name3     updatelink
```

where name is unique. After selecting the particular row i have to click update link. where update link has the same xpath for all rows

Comment: use css selector if all has same xpath then.

Comment: We have to use xpath as per our comp standars.

Comment: use `//td[contains(.,'name1')]/followwing-sibling::td/a`

Comment: @VivekSingh : Add it as answer. I think this is what OP needs. :)

Comment: Provide the HTML of the table

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
//td[contains(.,'name1')]/following-sibling::td/a
```